useDropzone causing 500 on refresh in Next.js App on Vercel
We're using dropzone in a Next.js app hosted on Vercel.
When the page loads from being navigated from somewhere else in the app it's fine. If you refresh the page with that URL or load directly there is a 500 error and the following error in the server logs.

The only way I can get rid of it is taking DropZone out, but we'd quite like to keep dropzone.
